# if(x in y) not working in python file I/O

Tags: python, file, io

I am creating a high scores database and so far 2 things do not work.

1. If I enter a name that is already in the file, it ignores the if statement (mentioned in code) I will put an comment on which line it is.
2. When I enter a name and a score, it replaces the current name and score that is in the highscores.txt file.

Here is my file:

```
name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
score = str(input("Enter your score: "))


file = open("N:\highscores.txt", "r")
if(name in file):
    print("You have already entered a score.")
    file.close()
else:
    file = open("N:\highscores.txt", "w")
    file.writelines(name + " : " + score + "\n")
    file.close()
```

Also, when I do fix this problem, how would I order them in size order? for example:
1. 450  2. 300 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to use `file.read()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python file objects do not support `in` membership testing, no.

Read the file into a dictionary, then test against that:

```
with open("N:\highscores.txt", "r") as scoresfile:
    scores = {name.strip(): score.strip() for line in scoresfile if ':' in line for name, score in (line.split(':'),)}

if name in scores:
    print("You have already entered a score.")
else:
    with open("N:\highscores.txt", "a") as scoresfile:
        file.write('{} : {}\n'.format(name, score))
```

Note that you need to open the file in *append* mode to add lines; `w` will first *clear* the opened file.

Comment: it comes up with an error - `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @user2816683: Right, you probably have an empty line in the file. Updated to only split lines with a colon.

Comment: Thanks. When I enter the first score, it is ok. But when I type the same name and score it comes up with the same error.

Comment: @user2816683: my apologies. corrected and this time I tested first. :-)

Answer (score 2):

By open you are just making the file ready to be used. You have to do a `file.read()` for the contents of the file to be read to be used